# NPM multiple install errors

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-gyp

When I try to install npm the console gives the following errors & warnings:

```html
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\web3
npm WARN ajv-keywords@2.1.1 requires a peer of ajv@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@2.1.0 requires a peer of babel-eslint@^7.2.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@2.1.0 requires a peer of eslint@^4.1.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-loader@1.9.0 requires a peer of eslint@>=1.6.0 <5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@5.1.1 requires a peer of eslint@^2.10.2 || ^3 || ^4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN firebase-functions@2.1.0 requires a peer of firebase-admin@~6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! path C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\web3
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, access 'C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\web3'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Aristophanes\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-02T23_13_12_948Z-debug.log
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `web3` folder in `C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\web3`, as well as the `node_modules` folder in your project directory (if exists). Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions for this.

```
**1. Reinstall npm with a Node version manager (recommended).**
```

This is the best way to avoid permissions issues. For more information, refer this link
[(https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node#using-a-version-manager-to-install-nodejs-and-npm)](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node#using-a-version-manager-to-install-nodejs-and-npm)
 You do not need to remove your current version of npm or Node.js before installing a Node version manager.

```
**2. Change npm's default directory manually.**
```

If you're not using windows you can use below steps.

```
To minimize the chance of permissions errors, you can configure npm to use a different directory. In this example, it will be a hidden directory on your home folder.

Back-up your computer before you start.

Make a directory for global installations:
```

mkdir ~/.npm-global

```
Configure npm to use the new directory path:
```

npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'

```
Open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:
```

export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH

```
Back on the command line, update your system variables:
```

source ~/.profile

Test: Download a package globally without using sudo.

npm install -g jshint

Instead of steps 2-4, you can use the corresponding ENV variable (e.g. if you don't want to modify ~/.profile):

```
 NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global
```

Comment: Does a Node version manager allow you to use older versions of Node, or older versions of Node modules? I'm getting the same Firebase warning, which is asking for firebase-admin 6.0.0, when I have firebase-admin 6.11.2 installed.